# Flutter different Android SDKs required on different machines

Tags: flutter

I recently moved from developing on a Macbook to a Linux machine. When trying to build my flutter project (exact same repo) from my Linux machine it fails and errors:

```
Warning: The plugin cloud_firestore requires Android SDK version 31.
One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
```

I find this strange as this project builds on my MacBook machine. I'd like to avoid bumping up my compile sdk. The plugin/dependency in question is this one:

```
cloud_firestore: ^2.4.0
```

PS: I checked the exact `firestore` versions on both machines (`pubspec.lock`) and it's the same... Also, I'm running the same java versions: `11.0.10`

```
  cloud_firestore:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: cloud_firestore
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.5.4"
```

Here's the full error:

```
One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to /home/somePathTo/fluterProject/android/app/build.gradle:
android {
  compileSdkVersion 31
  ...
}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

     The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
     Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
     AAR metadata file: /userPath/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/32b27b5f8d6f9e0567ff88e0d4cf2838/transformed/jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

     The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
     Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
     AAR metadata file: /userPath/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/1c53b8b701ed7a25b9b6c6d0093bc3c6/transformed/jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `flutter clean` followed by `flutter pub get`

If that doesn't work, I recommend the following:

1. Create a new flutter project and add all your dependencies, including Firestore. If it runs, then the problem is with the old project. Otherwise, you've either installed Firestore incorrectly or flutter itself.
2. Move the lib folder (and assets, if you have one) into the new project and run it. If it doesn't run, the problem is with the code.

That's how I'd tackle the issue, but I'm not sure if it's a good approach.

Comment: I tried cleaning the project but it didn't work. I also tried creating a new project with the same dependencies/lib and it works... something weird is happening here

Comment: Well, if you've managed to copy the lib and dependencies in a new project which runs, then the problem is solved, right? You just continue working on your app in another folder.